# How to set the values in a pandas dataframe column corresponding to an unused categorical interval index?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to compute a sort of Joint probability distribution from a dataframe containing two columns. However, I cannot find a way to add a column when the probability for a give column (or row) is always zero.

Consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(1000)*10
y = np.random.rand(1000)*8
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})

prob = df.groupby(
                   [pd.cut(df['x'], list(range(0,11))),
                    pd.cut(df['y'], list(range(0,11)))]
                 ).size().unstack().fillna(0) / len(df)
```

Since y ranges from 0 to 8, columns (8,9] and (9,10] do not exists in the dataframe. This is causing some troubles with the following code that is expecting a 10-by-10 dataframe.

However I cannot find a way to add a column as

```
interval = pd.Interval(left=8, right=9)
prob[interval] = 0
```

tells me `ValueError: cannot insert (8, 9], already exists` since

```
interval in prob.columns.categories
```

is `True`, but

```
prob[interval]
```

gives `KeyError: 8`.

**So how can I set a value for a category that is actually existing but unused?**

Comment: use `df.loc[]`, if you want to assign to index use `prob.loc[interval]`, if you want column use `df.loc[:,interval]`. Just to clarify this work on pandas version im using `0.23.4` not sure what differences will be regards to this on different versions.

Comment: `prob.loc[:,interval] = 0` returns the same error `ValueError: cannot insert (9, 10], already exists`

Comment: @gyx-hh have you tried it? its not working

Comment: Simply use `prob.loc[interval] = 0`.

Comment: @harvpan `prob.loc[:,interval]` is not working

Comment: @harvpan nope that zeros a row, it doesn't add a column... Is it *required* that the columns and indices be an `IntervalIndex`, or will just normal string labels suffice?

Comment: Hmm, I see. `interval`  is an instance of `Interval`. See `prob.columns`, they are all `CategoricalIndex`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to `.reindex` here.

Your indices already have the categories listed, but they are unused levels so somewhere the decision is being made to not create the "useless" rows or columns.

```
prob.columns.categories
#IntervalIndex([(0, 1], (1, 2], (2, 3], (3, 4], (4, 5], (5, 6], (6, 7], (7, 8], (8, 9], (9, 10]]
#              closed='right',
#              dtype='interval[int64]')
```

So explicitly reindex to those:

```
prob.reindex(prob.columns.categories, axis=1).fillna(0)
```

You can do the same along the index if need to ensure those are always there:

```
prob.reindex(prob.index.categories, axis=0).fillna(0)
```

#### Output:

```
y        (0, 1]  (1, 2]  (2, 3]  (3, 4]  (4, 5]  (5, 6]  (6, 7]  (7, 8]  (8, 9]  (9, 10]
x                                                                                       
(0, 1]    0.004   0.008   0.011   0.013   0.010   0.011   0.013   0.011     0.0      0.0
(1, 2]    0.007   0.013   0.013   0.015   0.017   0.015   0.009   0.014     0.0      0.0
(2, 3]    0.013   0.014   0.012   0.008   0.012   0.011   0.012   0.012     0.0      0.0
(3, 4]    0.014   0.014   0.010   0.012   0.016   0.016   0.013   0.008     0.0      0.0
(4, 5]    0.011   0.014   0.014   0.018   0.019   0.015   0.014   0.008     0.0      0.0
(5, 6]    0.011   0.012   0.012   0.012   0.013   0.013   0.014   0.011     0.0      0.0
(6, 7]    0.007   0.017   0.011   0.009   0.008   0.016   0.018   0.019     0.0      0.0
(7, 8]    0.015   0.010   0.008   0.012   0.012   0.008   0.016   0.013     0.0      0.0
(8, 9]    0.015   0.012   0.016   0.010   0.017   0.012   0.014   0.015     0.0      0.0
(9, 10]   0.008   0.010   0.012   0.018   0.008   0.012   0.019   0.011     0.0      0.0
```

Comment: great neat solution. I don't even have to look for which columns are missing. Everything is done automatically. Great! Thank you very much